# How to create a hierarchical relationship with dependency structures through montecarlo simulation

Tags: r, montecarlo, hierarchical

BACKGROUND

I am investigating if R is a suitable platform for some monte-carlo hierarchical modelling, and trying to solve the problem described below. Apologies for the length of the set-up.

SETUP

Consider a hierarchy with 3 levels (to start with, but I hope that I will be able to generalise the solution to any number of levels). The top level is labelled i, the second level is j and the third (bottom) level is k. Here

- i is 1 to l
- j is 1 to m
- k is 1 to n_ij

I start at the bottom of the tree. For each given i,j, I simulate n_ij correlated random variables X_ijk (eg lognormals with different means and SDs, with a gumbel dependency structure). This is reasonably straightforward.

I then sum the values together to climb the tree. So Y_ij = sum(X_ijk) from k = 1 to n_ij.

PROBLEM

At this point I wish to 
(1) force an additional dependency (eg Frank copula) between all the Y_ij's before summing to climb the tree again. 
(2) ensure that I do not lose the relative ordering on the level below (for tracking purposes)

POSSIBLE APPROACH

It's not clear how I would do this. The only approach I can think of is the steps below:
1. Simulate m uniforms with the appropriate copula dependency structure.
2. Re-shuffle the simulations in the Y_ij's so that they are 100% rank-tied with the output from (1). Maintain some sort of ordering / simulation number variable to allow tracking.

If this is the right approach, how do I go about doing (2)? If there is a better approach, what is it?

SIMPLE EXAMPLE

[Hierarchy Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIboq.jpg)
Here I am starting at the bottom of the tree, simulating copula-tied variables X_111 and X_112, and then summing to create Y_11. Then simulating copula-tied variables X_122 to X_124 and summing to create Y_12. I then wish to correlate Y_11 and Y_12 before summing to create Z_1.